# Loaded div accordion opening in window instead of container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

My parent page has divs loaded into a container div in a tab panel using ajax.

Parent Page markup:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tabs.css">
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.tab-link').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $("li.tab-link[data-tab='"+ tab_id+"']").addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');

  });

  $('#countries a.country').click(function() {
     var url=$(this).attr('href');
     $('#formcontainer').load(url + ' #form', function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    heightStyle: "content"
});
});


});
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul id="tabs" class="tabs">
<li id="tab1" class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">tab1</li>
    <li id="tab2" class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">tab2</li>
    <li id="tab3" class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">tab3</li>
    <li id="tab4" class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">tab4</li>
    <li id="tab5" class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-5">tab5</li>
</ul>
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">sgeagaetwwe</div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">adafsafarsv</div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">wefsfsdfsdfaa</div>
<div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">afafsgaafsdfd</div>
<div id="tab-5" class="tab-content">
<ul id="countries">
      <li><a class="country" href="form1.html">Form 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="country" href="form2.html">Form 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="country" href="form3.html">Form 3</a></li>
      <li><a class="country" href="form4.html">Form 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="formcontainer"></div>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Tabs.css:

```
.tabbox{
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        ul.tabs{
            margin: 0 0 -1px 0;
            padding: 0px;
            list-style: none;
        }
        ul.tabs li{
            background: #fff;
            color: #ff3399;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        ul.tabs li.current{
            background: #fff;
            border-top: 1px solid #999999;
            border-right: 1px solid #999999;
            border-left: 1px solid #999999;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
            color: #ff3399;
        }

        .tab-content{
            display: none;
            background: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #999999;
            padding: 15px;
        }

        .tab-content.current{
            display: inherit;
        }
```

Child page markup (form1.html):

```
    <html>
        <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script>
        $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    heightStyle: "content"
    });
        });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="form">
        <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <div>
        <p>
        Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. 
        </p>
        </div>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <div>
        <p>
        Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
        purus. 
        </p>
        </div>
        <h3>Section 3</h3>
        <div>
        <p>
        Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
        </p>
        </div>
        <h3>Section 4</h3>
        <div>
        <p>
        Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
        et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. 
        </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

My problem is that when the links are clicked on the parent page the div loads ok in the tab panel for a split second, and then opens up full screen. I am a real novice when it comes to writing js/jquery and the solution is probably really simple, but I can't get it to work. I have tried researching it but to no avail. Could it be a problem with the way I am calling the different functions? I've tried putting a return false; in the script but I might not have put it in the right place? I can get the divs to load into the tab panel *without* the accordion working, using this script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.tab-link').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $("li.tab-link[data-tab='"+ tab_id+"']").addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');

  });

  $('#countries a.country').click(function() {
     var url=$(this).attr('href');
     $('#formcontainer').load(url + ' #form');
     return false;


   });

});
        </script>
```

But it would be great if I can get the accordion to work too. Any help is much appeciated!

**EDIT:**

I have just realised my fancybox links inside the ajax loaded divs is also not working, I assume this is a related problem and I don't know how to fix this either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to load a whole page in which there is a accordion. To load a page you can use an iframe.


  `$('#countries a.country').click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

     if( $("#formcontainer").empty()){

        var url=$(this).attr('href');

        iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");  

        iframe.src = url + ' #form';

        iframe.style.width= "100%";

        iframe.style.border = 'none';

        $("#formcontainer").append(iframe);

     }
});`


But this may not be what you're looking for. Please check how the accordion is rendered in http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default

Comment: I'd prefer not to use an iframe, but I've just tried your suggestion. Strangely it seems to work offline, but in live mode I get a 404 error in the iframe, no matter how I try and link to the file in the #countries list link.

Comment: It's because you're not changing the relative url. var url=$(this).attr('href');
You see this comes from <li><a class="country" href="form1.html">Form 1</a></li>

Comment: I've tried changing the relative url in the li link and triple checked the file is in the correct location too, it just won't seem to work, it's bizarre. I have even tried <li><a class="country" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/form1.html">Form 1</a></li> but this doesn't work either. If I right click on the link and 'open in new tab' it loads the form1.html div just fine...but in a separate browser tab.

Comment: I found something which works - I removed
 + ' #form'
from the code, so it's now loading the whole page into the iframe not just the relevant div. The accordion form seems to be working in the iframe, now I've just got to see if I can get fancybox popups to work from within the iframe content..

Comment: It seems fancybox is now not supported by the latest jquery libraries and doesn't work online at all. Back to the drawing board methinks - maybe I will try using bootstrap for all my jquery needs. But I will probably use this new iframe method of loading the content, as the accordion seems to work ok in it. Thank you for the suggestion user2975123!